# Faster pagination with Doctrine 2.1 EXTRA_LAZY associations

Tags: performance, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination, associations

Doctrine 2.1 brings a new feature EXTRA_LAZY loading for associations: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

This feature creates a new method `slice($offset, $length)` to query just a page of the association and is very useful for pagination of large data sets.

However, behind the scene the SQL query uses the classic `LIMIT XX OFFSET XX` syntax which is slow for large data sets (https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/)

Is there a way to use the pagination with a `WHERE` clause?

If not, how may I extend the instance of `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` to create a method `sliceWithCursor($columnName, $cursor, $length)`?

My main goal is to implement a faster pagination while using the very convenient magic of Doctrine for associations.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`matching` function](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) of `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`, providing the criteria to filter, e.g.:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

$group = $entityManager->find('Group', $groupId);
$userCollection = $group->getUsers();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("birthday", "1982-02-17"))
    ->orderBy(array("username" => Criteria::ASC));

$birthdayUsers = $userCollection->matching($criteria);
```

[`matching()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.6/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php#L648) returns a `Doctrine\ORM\LazyCriteriaCollection`, if your association is defined as `EXTRA_LAZY`.

You can paginate with the latter:

```
$birthdayUsers->slice($offset, $length);
```

### Using cursor pagination

In some cases, it is required to use [cursor pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744926/offset-pagination-vs-cursor-pagination). You could do this by extending `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection`, as suggested:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

public function sliceWithCursor($criteria, $cursorEntity, $limit) {
    $orderBy = $criteria->getOrderings();

    foreach ($orderBy as $columnName => $direction) {        
        if ($direction === Criteria::ASC) {
           $criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->gte($columnName, $cursorEntity->{$columnName}));
        } else {
           $criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->lte($columnName, $cursorEntity->{$columnName}));
        }
    }

    // exclude cursor entity from the results
    $criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->neq("id", $cursorEntity->id));

    $criteria->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $this->matching($criteria);
}
```

The idea of cursor based pagination is to use a result row as starting point, instead of an offset, and get the next rows. As stated at [alternative for using OFFSET](https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/), the idea is to **substitute offset, with conditions from the order by clause**.